Why TreeMap in Java doesn't use Array as Buckets?
I was curious and started learning about how TreeMap is internally implemented in Java. And, I found out that it uses Red-Black Trees for keeping the sorted order of entries based on keys.
My question is why doesn't it use an Array as buckets as well along with the red-black tree. Wouldn't that make the search average time complexity as O(1) ?
I mean like LinkedHashMap maintains insertion order using Doubly Linked List as well as entries are hashed into array buckets based on keys and capacity. Why did Java developers not make TreeMap in a similar way ? It would not make insertion more time-taking complexity wise, right, as we only have to maintain pointers to left, right, parent etc. for each entry and update these based on insertion rules for red-black tree. I mean the whole process would be same, except mapping into array buckets. And the search would become O(1) if it's also mapped to array buckets. Am I missing something here ?

Are you asking why TreeMap doesn't keep a hash table for quicker lookup like LinkedHashMap keeps a linked list to preserve insertion order?

Yes, my question is exactly why TreeMap doesn't keep hash table, yes, like LinkedHashMap does. Now, I understand LinkedHashMap preserves insertion order by maintaining Doubly linked list internally, and similar thing is achieved for TreeMap by using red-black tree. But along with red-black tree, why wasn't hash table used to optimize search ?

Is it because developers didn't think of it, or is there a particular trade-off that they had in mind ?

I'm guessing the LinkedHashMap's linked list has a much lighter memory footprint than a whole parallel hash table. And you can always create your own parallel structure if it's an issue.

Right! But in terms of Big-O notation, the hash table would not be more than O(n), which red-black tree anyway had. So it won't really be affecting memory that much if we consider space complexity, as it will just be a constant multiplied to O(n) giving O(n) as resulting space complexity. Please correct me if I am wrong !
I mean I would like to see a TreeMap which has search in O(1) time without added space and time complexity for any operations in the future Java versions :)

See, LinkedHashMap insertion order maintenance is achieved using Doubly Linked List and TreeMap sorted order is maintained by Red-Black Tree. So the only difference is the hash table which is there for LinkedHashMap & HashMap but was chosen not to be included for TreeMap. But it won't change space and time complexity for any operations if it were included in TreeMap, but will reduce search to O(1). I guess O(logn) to O(1) is not considered that big a reduction maybe to include O(n) extra memory ?

Because it is a TreeMap and not a HashMap.

@user207421 Of course, that is true. I was just exploring and trying to understand the logic behind design choices and considering possibility of a "TreeHashMap", if you will.

TreeMap uses the comparator, and only the comparator, to look up elements.
That comparator is encouraged to be compatible with equals (and hashCode), but not required.  TreeMap cannot depend on hash codes, or it would violate its own rules.
Moreover, hashing can degenerate to O(n) when many keys hash into the same bucket, whereas binary search trees are guaranteed to be O(log n).  This is, in fact, why HashMaps fall back to binary search trees internally for bucket collisions.
If the user wanted to use hashes, they could.  If they chose a TreeMap, there's a reason they wanted its behavior.  This is not an oversight, and not a mistake.

I could still argue that it could be improved as a TreeHashMap, making most of the both worlds(TreeMap and HashMap) but then again, it would only improve average lookup to O(1) and worst-case would still fall-back to O(logn) as you rightly said, and I also was aware of it. But that's a great point to be considered, which I am able to digest now as in Computer Science, we mostly think about Worst-case complexities(with few exceptions like quicksort etc.) and thus adding complex mechanisms to improve only average case time complexity might not be a good reason. But, worth exploring, thanks!

Even a case as trivial as new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) can’t use hash codes, as they are not compatible. It’s also a common misconception that hashing was faster than binary search. A comparison usually stops at the first chars whereas calculating a hash code has to run over the entire string (the final, matching candidate has to be processed completely in either case). You need a significantly large number of elements to benefit from the O(1) time complexity. That’s actually exactly what looking at worst case complexity, as discussed in computer science, means.
